# using stl to run length encode a string using std::adjacent_find

Tags: algorithm, c++11, stl-algorithm

I am trying to perform run length compression on a string for a special protocol that I am using. Runs are considered efficient when the run size or a particular character in the string is >=3.  Can someone help me to achieve this.   I have **[live demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a42096e0606380db)**.  I am pretty sure this is possible with the standard library's `std::adjacent_find` with a combination of `std::not_equal_to<>` as the binary predicate to search for run boundaries and probably using `std::equal_to<>` once I find a boundary.   Here is what I have so far but I am having trouble with the results:

Given the following input text string containing runs or spaces and other characters (in this case runs of the letter 's':

```
"---thisssss---is-a---tesst--"
```

I am trying to convert the above text string into a vector containing elements that are either pure runs of > 2 characters or mixed characters.  The results are almost correct but not quite and I cannot spot the error.

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
expected the following
======================
---,thi,sssss,---,is-a,---,tesst--,
actual results
==============
---,thi,sssss,---,is-a,---,te,ss,--,
```

EDIT: I fixed up the previous code to make this version closer to the final solution.  Specifically I added explicit tests for the run size to be > 2 to be included.  I seem to be having boundary case problems though - the all spaces case and the case where the end of the strings ends in several spaces:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    // I want to convert this string containing adjacent runs of characters
    std::string testString("---thisssss---is-a---tesst--");

    // to the following 
    std::vector<std::string> idealResults = {
        "---", "thi", "sssss",
        "---", "is-a",
        "---", "tesst--"
    };

    std::vector<std::string> tokenizedStrings;
    auto adjIter = testString.begin();
    auto lastIter = adjIter;
    // temporary string used to accumulate characters that 
    // are not part of a run.
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> stringWithoutRun;
    while ((adjIter = std::adjacent_find(
        adjIter, testString.end(), std::not_equal_to<>())) !=
        testString.end()) {
        auto next = std::string(lastIter, adjIter + 1);
        // append to foo if < run threshold
        if (next.length() < 2) {
            if (!stringWithoutRun) {
                stringWithoutRun = std::make_unique<std::string>();
            }
            *stringWithoutRun += next;
        } else {
            // if we have encountered non run characters, save them first
            if (stringWithoutRun) {
                tokenizedStrings.push_back(*stringWithoutRun);
                stringWithoutRun.reset();
            }
            tokenizedStrings.push_back(next);
        }
        lastIter = adjIter + 1;
        adjIter = adjIter + 1;
    }
    tokenizedStrings.push_back(std::string(lastIter, adjIter));

    std::cout << "expected the following" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "======================" << std::endl;
    std::copy(idealResults.begin(), idealResults.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "actual results" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============" << std::endl;
    std::copy(tokenizedStrings.begin(), tokenizedStrings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: why not_equal_to<>()(*adjIter, *next) instead of *adjIter != *next ?

Comment: I doesn't make any difference and it has nothing to do with solving my algorithm shortcomings.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (next.length() < 2) {
    if (!stringWithoutRun) {
        stringWithoutRun = std::make_unique<std::string>();
    }
    *stringWithoutRun += next;
}
```

This should be `if (next.length() <= 2)`. You need to add a run of identical characters to the current token if its length is either `1` or `2`.

> I seem to be having boundary case problems though - the all spaces
>   case and the case where the end of the strings ends in several spaces

When `stringWithoutRun` is not empty after the loop finishes, the characters accumulated in it are not added to the array of tokens. You can fix it like this:

```
// The loop has finished
if (stringWithoutRun)
    tokenizedStrings.push_back(*stringWithoutRun);
tokenizedStrings.push_back(std::string(lastIter, adjIter));
```